# Sails.js view to pdf

Tags: node.js, pdf, sails.js, view

What is the best approach for converting already existing views to downloadable pdf files in sails.js? I already have my views in sails with desired format, and now my objective is to turn them to pdf files. Are there packages that can get this going faster , if so which would best be recommended?

Answer (score 0):

If "already have my views in sails with desired format" means that you are creating HTML output in the desired output now, then have a look at [`node-html-pdf`](https://github.com/marcbachmann/node-html-pdf).

Comment: How do I get this html-pdf to read my css and images? I've gotten it to get the data to the pdf, however it's just plain raw html. I've been trying a couple of things but so far unsuccessful in getting it to render my css formatting properly.